# Can multiple main method of class A can be called from another class B main method

Tags: java

I want to call the main method of the same class with different string arguments from another class main method.

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] testArgs = {"Hi", "Helloworld" };

        B.main(testArgs );

        String[] testArgs1 = {"Hi", "Java" };

        B.main(testArgs1 );

    }

}

public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(args[0] + " " + args[1]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should be able to, what is stopping you from trying it out?

Comment: What is exactly your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can call a main method exactly like you would call any other static method, from within the same class or from another class (as you already do).

1) If you put two classes, like A and B, in the same source file, exacly one of must be declared public. The name of this public class must be the prefix of the name of the file. (So, if A is the public class, the name of the file must be A.java, if stored in a ordinary file system.)

2) If you put A and B in separate source files, they can both be public.

Regardless of how you choose to store the classes, you call the main methods the same way. To call B's main method from A, write just

```
B.main( ... )
```

Comment: As you said in the 2 point, i did in that way. But its executing only the first call not the second one.

Comment: Hm, strange. I see no reason why only the first call to B.main, and not both, should be executed. Are you running A?

Comment: Yes. I am running A

Comment: Sorry.. Slight mistake in the code. In my code i am having System.exit(0) thats why it is not allowing the next main to call. Thanks Hakan for your help.

Comment: Can you please tell, my class B is having System.exit(0) for successful termination from JVM, if i remove that code any impact will happen.

Comment: Unless your program runs threads, access files etc there is little use calling System.exit. Normal practice is to just let the main-method end. Your code does not contain any call to System.exit so I can't tell what happens if you remove it. I suggest you try - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can ,but you just need to remove "public" from class B because in java a file have only one public class.

Comment: I don't want to change the class B code and want to execute class A. how I can do that. as suggested by you when I am removing the public from Class A main method I am not able to execute this

Comment: If you remove public from class A then rename your java file to B to be executed by JVM . Now your Main class is B.

Comment: I am using Project with ClassB as a jar in the Project with Class A. Now, i want to call the main method of B two times with different string args from Class A project. This is my use case, can you paste sample code to achieve this.

Comment: you can execute your goal to directly call class A using cmd .
````
java -cp sample.jar com.test.A arg1 arg2

Comment: Yes, we can. But we can't use this one for mac users.